# 12.04 cannot boot from USB

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb, uefi, secure-boot

The **HP Pavilion g6** notebook is unable to boot from bootable USB stick created with **Linux Live USB Creator**. I was able to boot other systems using the same pendrive.

I have changed the boot priority using <kbd>F10</kbd>. When I restarted, it didn't ask for any message like

> Press any key to boot from

When I press <kbd>F19</kbd>, and selected the pendrive from the available options to boot from, while restarting it gives me a message:

```
error while trying to boot selected boot image
```

Though I looked into the possible suggestions here, none of them worked. Looking for any help?

EDIT: I was able to fix the first issue, i'e ubuntu could be installed as secure boot option in the bios was not allowing the pendrive or cd/dvd to be detected. Now once i have successfully installed ubuntu 12.04, after the restart i was unable to find it in the os menu for selection and windows8 loaded by default

Ubuntu version: 12.04

Comment: What version of **Ubuntu** did you create the USB boot media with?  Was the OS fully updated?

Comment: i used 12.04, the issue is fixed as it was due to some issues of uefi from windows8 which was already installed. but currently after  installation cannot the ubuntu options alongside windows8 for login

Comment: Please reword.  Can you add more detail to the question (above).

Comment: @david6 i have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
The lappy comes with windows 8, so in order to boot from external device i had to enter into the bios and disable secure boot(set secure boot to false), which solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the iso on your pc try dd the iso to your usb stick
dd if=/path/ot/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/usb-stick bs=4M 
to know which /dev is ur usb type fdisk -l